# Adding Custom Image in Highcharts while Exporting images/PDF

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to add the user logo in the image while exporting in High-charts. It was success in excel file export, but not able to get on how to do it in for images /pdf. There is no much information on High-charts as well.

Any help or advice will be helpful.

Updation:-

My requirement is to add my new image in the graph image. like, user image at top and below it graph will be displayed. Currently, it just adds image at provided location at the background. –

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, i saw that answer. my requiement is to add mu new image in the grpah image. like, user image at top and below it graph will be displayed. Currently, it just addes image at provided location at the background.

Comment: Then just set higher marginTop for the chart when exporting and there render that image.

Comment: I tried with chart.width and height, but it makes the chart on website small and not in the image.

Comment: Set that options in `chartOptions`. Just like in the main topic.